# Does the employer social security tax also apply on self-employment income for individuals with W2 income that exceeds the IRS maximum?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, self-employment, social-security

I have a question very similar to [W2 and 1099 (self employed) income in same year: social security taxable income limit?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/21664/w2-and-1099-self-employed-income-in-same-year-social-security-taxable-income), but goes a step further.

The goal of my question is to estimate how much social security tax would be taken out from a side-hustle while earning income from a W2 that is in excess of the IRS [Maximum Taxable Earnings](https://www.ssa.gov/benefits/retirement/planner/maxtax.html).

Question: If an employee receives both a W2 income in excess of the IRS maximum taxable earnings, and they are also self-employed on the side, would the employer portions of self-employed social security tax still apply on the self-employment income?

For example, imagine someone works a W2 job and makes $200,000 (in excess of the social security limit). Their employer would withhold 6.2% (up to the same maximum?).

If the same someone also is self-employed and makes $10,000 through some side gig. This income would also be subject social security tax of 12.4% -- 6.2% for the employee and 6.2% as the employer.

The employees gross wages in this example, as I understand it, is $210,000 (since the income is "pass-through"). This means that up to the IRS limit (e.g. $147,000 in 2022) the 6.2% tax would be applied.

However I'm not as clear on how the employer portion works. For the self-employment portion of the income $10,000, would that also be subject to the additional 6.2% from the "employer" portion of the self-employment income?

Meaning in total with this hypothetical, the total social security taxes owed would be:

- Employee social security: $147,000 & 6.2% = $9,114
- Employer social security: $10,000 & 6.2% = $620
- Total: $9,114 + $620 = $9,734

Is this correct? Or am I missing something?

Following up on that, does the employer portion of social security also follow the same maximums? (E.g. assume $200,000 in W2 income but now $150,000 in self-employment income).

In this new example, would the employer social security portion only apply to the first $147,000 (2022 IRS limit) of the $150,000 in self-employment profit?

Comment: What IRS limit are you talking about? Are you referring to the Social Security maximum taxable earnings?

Comment: Yes. Sorry if that wasn't clear. The values described here: https://www.ssa.gov/benefits/retirement/planner/maxtax.html. (Edit: updated the post to use the phrase 'maximum taxable earnings' and link to the doc. hopefully it's more clear now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your W2 wages subject to social security taxes exceed the maximum taxable earnings ($147000 for 2022), you do not need to pay the Social Security component of the self-employment tax, only the Medicare.

From [the IRS (numbers updated to 2020)](https://www.irs.gov/businesses/small-businesses-self-employed/self-employment-tax-social-security-and-medicare-taxes):

> If your wages and tips are subject to either social security tax or the Tier 1 part of railroad retirement tax, or both, and total at least $137,700, do not pay the 12.4% social security part of the SE tax on any of your net earnings. However, you must pay the 2.9% Medicare part of the SE tax on all your net earnings.

Answer (score 1):

The sum of the Social Security taxes paid from W-2 wages and the Social Security taxes paid for self employment (both the employee and employer parts) will not exceed the maximum amount.

For example, look at the [2021 Form 1040 Schedule SE](https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-prior/f1040sse--2021.pdf). The maximum taxable earnings ($142,800 for 2021) is on line 7. On line 9, you decrease line 7 by the amount of your Social Security wage compensation; this serves as the maximum taxable earnings for Social Security. On line 10, you multiply the lesser of line 6 (92.35% of your income) and line 9 (the limit decreased by Social Security wages) by 12.4%, and this is the Social Security part of your Self-Employment Tax. Notice that 12.4% is both the employer and employee portions (each of which is 6.2%). You can see that if your W-2 Social Security wages reaches the maximum taxable earnings, lines 9 and 10 will be 0 (and in fact, on line 8a, it says if your wages exceeds $142800, to skip lines 8b through 10, implying that the Social Security part of Self-Employment tax is 0). The Medicare part of Self-Employment Tax (line 11) is unaffected by the limit.